# Error:Uncaught TypeError: $(...).valid is not a function while using ('#form').valid()

Tags: jquery, razor, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

Here is my page where I want to check is form valid or not from jquery function..Code is as follows:

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">

    <div class="row" style="width:80%;padding-top:20px;margin-left:3%;">
        @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "addNominationForm"}))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="white-bg" style="padding-left:2%">

                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group" style="padding-top:10px">

                    @Html.Label("Nomination Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 requiredfeild", style = "text-align: left" })
                    <div>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AwardId, @ViewBag.Awards as SelectList, "Select", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, id = "Award", style = "width:25%" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("Resource From", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 requiredfeild", style = "text-align: left" })
                    <div>
                        <label> @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SelectResourcesBy, "Project", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, id = "ProjectRadioButton" })Project</label>
                        &nbsp;
                        <label> @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SelectResourcesBy, "Department", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, id = "DepartmentRadioButton" })Department</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <input type="hidden" name=ManagerId value=@ViewBag.ManagerId>

                <div class="form-group" id="projectInput">
                    @Html.Label("Project", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 requiredfeild", style = "text-align: left" })
                    <div>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjectID, @ViewBag.ProjectsUnderCurrentUser as SelectList, "Select", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, id = "SelectedProject", style = "width:25%" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" id="departmentInput">
                    @Html.Label("Department", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 requiredfeild", style = "text-align: left" })
                    <div>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DepartmentId, @ViewBag.DepartmentsUnderCurrentUser as SelectList, "Select", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, id = "SelectedDepartment", style = "width:25%" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("Resource Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3 requiredfeild", style = "text-align: left" })
                    <div>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ResourceId, @ViewBag.Resources as SelectList, "Select", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, id = "Resources", style = "width:25%" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom:10px">
                    @Html.Label("Is PLC ?", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3", style = "text-align: left" })
                    <div>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsPLC, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, id = "IsPlcCheckbox" }) Yes
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                    <div id="Criterias">
                        <table class="table table-hover issue-tracker white-bg" id="criteriaTable"></table>
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group white-bg" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom;padding-left:2%">
                @Html.Label("Comment", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 requiredfeild", style = "text-align: left" })
                <div>
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.MainComment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, id = "managerComment", style = "min-width: 80%", rows = "7", placeholder = "If candidate is selected as winner, this text will be shared across the company" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-3">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Draft" id="saveButton" class="btn btn-warning btnSameSize" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-success-green btnSameSize" onclick="return checkCriteriaComments();" />
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-danger btnSameSize" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Dashboard", "Dashboard")'" />
                </div>
            </div>

        }
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    function checkCriteriaComments() {
        var comments = 0;

         if($("#addNominationForm").valid())
         {
               alert("valid form");
         }    


        $(".criteriaComment").children("textarea").each(function (data) {
            if ($(this).val().trim())
                comments++;
        });

        if (!$("#Award").val()) {
            $("#Award").tooltip({ title: "Select Award.", placement: 'right' }).tooltip('show');
            return false;
        }

        else if (comments < 1) {
            $(".criteriaComment").children("textarea").first().tooltip({ title: "Enter at least one criteria comment.", placement: 'right' }).tooltip('show');
            return false;
        }
        else if (!$("#managerComment").val()) {
            $("#managerComment").tooltip({ title: "Enter main comment.", placement: 'right' }).tooltip('show');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            swal({
                title: "Add Nomination",
                text: "Do you want to nominate this candidate?",
                type: "info",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#88a364",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes!",
                cancelButtonText: "No!",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                closeOnCancel: false
            },
              function (isConfirm) {
                  if (isConfirm) {
                      debugger;
                      var model = $('#addNominationForm').serialize()

                      $.ajax({
                          type: 'post',
                          url: '@Url.Action("AddNomination", "Nomination")',
                          data: JSON.stringify({ model: model,submit:"Submit" }),
                          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                          success: function (data) {
                              swal({
                                  title: "Nominated Successfully",
                                  showCancelButton: false,
                                  confirmButtonColor: "#88a364",
                                  confirmButtonText: "Ok"
                              },
                              function () {
                                  if (isConfirm) {
                                      window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Dashboard", "Dashboard")';
                                  }
                              });
                          }
                      });
                  } else {
                      swal("Cancelled", "Nomination Cancelled");
                  }
              });

            return true;
        }

    }
    }

</script>
```

This is my model:

```
  public class NominationViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select Award")]
        public int AwardId { get; set; }

        public int NominationId { get; set; }
        public int ManagerId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select Resource")]
        public int ResourceId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select Project")]
        public int? ProjectID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select Department")]
        public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public bool IsPLC { get; set; }
        public bool? IsSubmitted { get; set; }

        public string MainComment { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select Project or Department")]
        public string SelectResourcesBy { get; set; }  //from project or from department

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide comment against criteria")]
        public IList<CriteriaCommentViewModel> Comments { get; set; }

        public NominationViewModel()
        {
            Comments = new List<CriteriaCommentViewModel>();
        }

    }
```

Here when I debug the script code in browser then it gave "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).valid is not a function" this error on valid() function..How can solve this problem? thanks in advance...

Comment: You're missing `$` in `if(("#addNominationForm").valid())`

Comment: even afte adding $ it is showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

> "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).valid is not a function"

[As per the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid), you can only use `.valid()` sometime *after* `.validate()` is called.

> `validate()` needs to be called on the form before checking it using this method.

Since you're using a Microsoft framework, `.validate()` is constructed and called automatically by the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` plugin.

You're going to have to inspect your live DOM to see where `.validate()` is called and make sure that your call to `.valid()` is moved to someplace *after* the `.validate()` call.

Comment: how can i check valid field based on data annotations given in viewmodel?

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav, the plugin takes care of that automatically and `.valid()` simply forces it to check programatically.  Refer to your documentation for the Unobtrusive Validation plugin.

Comment: I just want to check if the fields on the view are valid(based on data annotation) in the jqery function..How can I achive it?

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav, that is all done automatically!  **Refer to your documentation for the Unobtrusive Validation plugin.**  Otherwise, I've fully explained why you're getting the error message you've described.

Comment: If I call validate() before valid() then it is giving same error:"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function"

Comment: You **cannot** call `.validate()` since you are already using the Unobtrusive Validation plugin. I thought I already explained this in my answer:  **"`.validate()` is constructed and called automatically by the jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js plugin"**

Comment: You really need to **read the documentation** about how to properly implement these plugins.  Good luck.

Comment: Then how can I track why valid() doesnt work approapriately?

Comment: Yes,will check..Thank you

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav, read my answer again!  Did you inspect your live DOM?

Comment: Yes but didnt get what particular thing in DOM u wanted to inspect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114140/discussion-between-abhishek-jadhav-and-sparky).

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav, don't take offense, but I think you might have a reading issue.  Re-read the last paragraph of my answer:  "You're going to have to **inspect your live DOM** to see where `.validate()` is called and make sure...."

Comment: Sorry but i dont how to do it

Answer (score -1):

This error

```
Error:Uncaught TypeError: $(…).valid is not a function while using ('#form').valid
```

is mainly due to plugins overlaps.So check plugins and include correctly the plugins. I had that error and added jquery-validating plugins in a proper way.

Answer (score -2):

The possible reason is, you haven't linked your libraries properly or libraries missing. As a result, it fails to recognize the function with `$(whatever).valid()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is incorrect. See the comment above.